# keep aspect ratio of background image

Tags: android, android-studio, background

Lets say I have a big image, something like 2000x3000px, and want to cut out an 1080x1920px image and put it as the background of my app. What I figured out is that every device with a viewport of 412x732 will display this image correct (no different factor for stretching in height and width). The aspect ratio will be the same and therefore an object of the 1080x1920 image wont look stretched in height while maintaining the same width on an 1440x2560px (viewport 412x732) device. However when displaying this image on an 1080x2280px device (viewport 412x869) the image will look stretched (like you can see in the right image). Now I wonder how I can implement background images for different aspect ratios so that such stretching wont occur on any device. Instead I want that more parts of the original big image are displayed on screens with larger (or less image on smaller) aspect ratio devices.
Imagine the black border of the image is the original 2000x3000px, the blue border would be the image on an 1080x1920 device and the green border would be an 1080x2280 device. I hope you get the idea what I mean.

[image: Example Image: No draw skill sorry]

After some research I found the option to use an ImageView with `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` rather than putting the image as background. However I don't know if this will solve my problem. What do you guys think would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

With the `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` you should additionally put `ImageView` on every your screen. This would be fine if you have only 1 screen, otherwise you will need to duplicate same trick.
If you need the same background of windows to be set as theme property so you could wrap your image with drawable resource. Something like:

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/bg_image"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center|bottom|clip_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Playing with gravity you'll be able to receive preferred result with scaling/positioning.
To set image as a theme property you need to add it in styles `AppTheme`:

```xml
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/you_image_as_a_layer_list</item>
```